# How to create Javafx save, read information from text file and letting user to edit their information

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

How to create JavaFx RegisterGUI save user information(Username,password,name,email,phone number,address) and load into UserProfile GUI that allow the user to edit their profile information after login with their username and password? Hope you guys can help me with the problems.

UserGUI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.GUIButton">
  <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Button id="btnEdit" fx:id="btnEdit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setOnAction" text="Edit Profile" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
      <Button id="btnSave" fx:id="btnSave" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setOnAction" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="73.0" text="Save" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
      <Button id="btnCancel" fx:id="btnCancel" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setOnAction" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="66.0" text="Cancel" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
      <Text id="txtName" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Text id="txtPhoneNumber" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Phone Number" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Text id="txtEmail" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Email" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
      <Text id="txtAddress" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Address" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
      <TextField id="txtfName" onAction="#setOnAction" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="203.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <TextField id="txtfPhoneNumber" onAction="#setOnAction" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <TextField id="txtfEmail" onAction="#setOnAction" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
      <TextArea id="txtaAddress" onDragDetected="#setOnAction" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
      <ImageView id="imgUser" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

RegisterGUI :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<GridPane id="RegisterGUI" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" fx:controller="application.RegisterButton">
  <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="193.5999755859375" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="151.20003662109374" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="193.5999755859375" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="151.20003662109374" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="447.9999633789063" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="447.9999633789063" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Email" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Username" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="IC Number" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Phone Number" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Address" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
      <TextField id="txtfEmail" fx:id="txtfEmail" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <TextField id="txtfUsername" fx:id="txtfUsername" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <TextField id="txtfName" fx:id="txtfName" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
      <TextField id="txtfIC" fx:id="txtfIC" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
      <TextField id="txtfPhone" fx:id="txtfPhone" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
      <TextArea id="txtaAddress" fx:id="txtaAddress" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
      <Button id="btnRegister" fx:id="btnRegister" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#OnRegister" text="Register" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
      <Button id="btnExit" fx:id="btnExit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#OnExit" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="56.0" text="Exit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Password" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <TextField id="txtfPassword" fx:id="txtfPassword" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok build a small login, Signup, and Edit app for you**, You can modify it as u like

[image] 
[image]

So we have 4 class files. and 2 FXML files and Textfile

[image]

**Luncher.java**

```
    package loginApplication;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Luncher extends Application{

    public static Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        stage = primaryStage;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**LoginController.java**

```
package loginApplication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class LoginController 
{

    @FXML
    private TextField email_textfield;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField password_textfield;


    @FXML
    private Label error_lab;



    @FXML
    public void signupButton(ActionEvent event) {
        openWindow();
    }

    @FXML
    public void loginButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException 
    {   


        //Path to text file
        Path path = Paths.get("TextFiles/data.txt");

        //Counts number of line in text file
        long count = Files.lines(path).count();

        /// read each line
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
           {
                String line = Files.readAllLines(path).get(i);
                if(!line.trim().equals("")) 
                {

                    //According to format Name, Email, Password, Age, Gender
                    String[] profile = line.split(",");

                    String name = profile[0];
                    String email = profile[1];
                    String password = profile[2];
                    String age = profile[3];
                    String gender =  profile[4];
                    String contact =  profile[5];

                    //Email Matched!
                    if(email.trim().equals(email_textfield.getText()))
                    { //Note trim() method remove space from front and behind of string if there is any
                        //Now checking if password match
                        if(password.trim().equals(password_textfield.getText())) 
                        {

                            Alert msg = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                            msg.setTitle(email_textfield.getText());
                            msg.setContentText("Email and password matched");
                            msg.showAndWait();

                            //Store values
                            Storage.setName(name);
                            Storage.setEmail(email);
                            Storage.setAge(age);
                            Storage.setGender(gender);
                            Storage.setContact(contact);
                            Storage.setPassword(password);

                            //open login window
                            openWindow();

                            break; //Email match and pass match, Close loop

                        }


                    } 




               }   



            }

           if(Storage.getEmail() == null) {
                System.out.println("No such email");

                Alert msg = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                msg.setTitle(email_textfield.getText());
                msg.setContentText("No such Email : " +email_textfield.getText());
                msg.showAndWait();

               } else if (Storage.getPassword() == null){
                    System.out.println("No such email");

                    Alert msg = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                    msg.setTitle(email_textfield.getText());
                    msg.setContentText("Wrong password");
                    msg.showAndWait();
               }

    }

    private void openWindow() 
    {
        System.out.println("Profile open");

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Profile.fxml"));
            Luncher.stage.setScene(new Scene(root));



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

**ProfileController.java**

```
package loginApplication;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ProfileController implements Initializable{



    @FXML
    private TextField name;

    @FXML
    private TextField email;

    @FXML
    private TextField gender;

    @FXML
    private TextField contact;

    @FXML
    private TextField age;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        name.setText(Storage.getName());
        age.setText(Storage.getAge());
        gender.setText(Storage.getGender());
        email.setText(Storage.getEmail());
        contact.setText(Storage.getContact());
        password.setText(Storage.getPassword());


        //Open windows for sign up if nall else do this
        if(Storage.getEmail() !=null)
        {
            //Disable everything
            name.setDisable(true);
            age.setDisable(true);
            gender.setDisable(true);
            email.setDisable(true);
            contact.setDisable(true);
            password.setDisable(true);
        } 




    }

    @FXML
    private Button save;

    @FXML
    private Button edit;



    @FXML
    void editButton(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        System.out.println("edit button");
        //Active everything
        name.setDisable(false);
        age.setDisable(false);
        gender.setDisable(false);
        email.setDisable(false);
        contact.setDisable(false);
        password.setDisable(false);
    }

    @FXML
    void saveButton(ActionEvent event) {
        //Disable everything
        name.setDisable(true);
        age.setDisable(true);
        gender.setDisable(true);
        email.setDisable(true);
        contact.setDisable(true);
        password.setDisable(true);

        removeLine();
        addLine();
    }

    private void addLine() {
        String line = name.getText() +"," +email.getText() +"," +password.getText() +"," +age.getText() +"," +gender.getText()+"," +contact.getText();

         FileWriter file_writer;
        try {
            file_writer = new FileWriter("TextFiles/data.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter buffered_Writer = new BufferedWriter(file_writer);
            buffered_Writer.write(line);
            buffered_Writer.flush();
            buffered_Writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Add line failed!!" +e);
        }

    }

    private void removeLine() {
         try
            {
                    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TextFiles/data.txt"));
                    String line;
                    String input = "";
                    while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        //System.out.println(line);
                        if (line.contains(Storage.getEmail()))
                        {
                            line = "";
                            System.out.println("Line deleted.");
                        }
                        input += line + '\n';
                    }
                    FileOutputStream File = new FileOutputStream("TextFiles/data.txt");
                    File.write(input.getBytes());
                    file.close();
                    File.close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
            }



    }

}
```

**Storage.java**

```
package loginApplication;

public class Storage {

    private static String Name;
    private static String Age;
    private static String Gender;
    private static String Email;
    private static String Contact;
    private static String password;

    // This is how u should do it but u can also make field public and use them directly 
    // for example -> 'Public static String Name' then use it as 'Storage.name'

    public static String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public static void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public static String getAge() {
        return Age;
    }
    public static void setAge(String age) {
        Age = age;
    }
    public static String getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }
    public static void setGender(String gender) {
        Gender = gender;
    }
    public static String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }
    public static void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }
    public static String getContact() {
        return Contact;
    }
    public static void setContact(String contact) {
        Contact = contact;
    }
    public static String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public static void setPassword(String password) {
        Storage.password = password;
    }



}
```

**Login.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onDragDetected="#loginButton" prefHeight="390.0" prefWidth="304.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="loginApplication.LoginController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="email_textfield" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="83.0" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="229.0" promptText="Email">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <PasswordField fx:id="password_textfield" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="152.0" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="229.0" promptText="Password" />
      <Button layoutX="87.0" layoutY="222.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loginButton" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="131.0" text="Login" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#328d38">
         <font>
            <Font name="Courier New Bold" size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Label fx:id="error_lab" layoutX="59.0" layoutY="284.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="229.0" textFill="#ee0c0c">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button layoutX="110.0" layoutY="284.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#signupButton" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="Sign up" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#3b21e4">
         <font>
            <Font name="Courier New Bold" size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Profile.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="420.0" prefWidth="560.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="loginApplication.ProfileController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="edit" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="363.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editButton" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="111.0" text="Edit">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <TextField fx:id="name" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="329.0" promptText="Name">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <TextField fx:id="email" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="242.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="329.0" promptText="Email">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <TextField fx:id="gender" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="132.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="329.0" promptText="Gender">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <TextField fx:id="contact" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="187.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="329.0" promptText="Contact">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <TextField fx:id="age" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="81.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="329.0" promptText="Age">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <Button fx:id="save" layoutX="420.0" layoutY="363.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveButton" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="111.0" text="Save">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <PasswordField fx:id="password" layoutX="202.0" layoutY="297.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="329.0" promptText="Password">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </PasswordField>
      <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="34.0" text="Name">
         <font>
            <Font name="Cambria Math" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="88.0" text="Age">
         <font>
            <Font name="Cambria Math" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="139.0" text="Gender">
         <font>
            <Font name="Cambria Math" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="194.0" text="Contact">
         <font>
            <Font name="Cambria Math" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="249.0" text="Email">
         <font>
            <Font name="Cambria Math" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="35.0" layoutY="304.0" text="Password">
         <font>
            <Font name="Cambria Math" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**I hope this help if something wont work or u need to know something ask it :)**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an SQLite database and Not textfile.

But using a Text file to make a small database it's a good practice.

To do this you need to create a .txt file that's your database
In a text file, you can store information many ways for example
Name, Email, Password, Age, Gender

- Jack, jack@gmail.com, mypassword123, 18, male,
- Adam, adam101@gmail.com, adampas1001, 21, female,

in this way you separating data with commas
Now you have to read each line 1 by 1

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class TextFileReader
{   
//  Location / count / List
    private String text_File_Location; //location
    private long count;

    public TextFileReader(String url)
    {   
        this.text_File_Location = url;
        lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
        countLines();
        initFontCodeList();


    }


    //Counts number of lines mean number of profiles
    private void countLines()
    {
        try {
            count = Files.lines(Paths.get(text_File_Location)).count();
        } catch (IOException e1) { System.err.println("TextFileReader : Count Failed" +e1); }
    }

    //init List
    private void initFontCodeList() {
        try 
        {

             Path path = Paths.get(text_File_Location);

               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
               {
                    String line = Files.readAllLines(path).get(i);
                                        //Acording to format Name, Email, Password, Age, Gender
                String[] profile = line.split(",");
                String name = profile[0];
                String email = profile[1];
                String Password = profile[2];
                String age = profile[4];
                String gender =  profile[5];


               }


        } 
        catch (IOException e) {System.err.println("TextFileReader : ReadFile Failed");}
    }



}
```

Now just use a couple of logic to check if an information entered on GUI is equal textfile information

**Removing profile** is just deleting that line

**Modifying profile** is just deleting that line and creating another line

This is all the basic how to start

Comment: textfieldName.setText(data u receive);
I guess ur new to java fx. u need to play with it a little.

Comment: Yea I just started to learn javafx have a lot of problem understanding. Now I stuck with the Login part, need the user to login with registered data of username and password in a text file. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: yes, I build those kinds of application with .txt files and with the database as well.  are you confident with ur basic java? and u know how methods and classes work ? then it not much hard trust me. Let me provide u better example